# The ModelResource Meta field import_id_fields seems that it doesn't work as expected

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm building a web app using the Django framework and the django-import-export package.
I would like to import data from files and want to prevent importing it twice to the DB.

For this, I used the `import_id_fields` when declaring the resource class, but it seems that it doesn't work as expected.

1- The first time I import the file everything is working fine and rows created in the DB.

2- The second time I import the same file, also new rows created in the DB (here is the problem, this is not supposed to happen)

3- The third time I import the same file, here I get errors and no rows added to the DB.

So I would like to know if this is normal behavior or not, and if is normal I would like to know how can I stop the import in point 2 and show the errors.

You can find below portions from the code and the error messages.

```py
# resources.py
class OfferingResource(ModelResource):
    ACCESSIONNUMBER = Field(attribute='company',
                            widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Company, 'accession_number'))
    quarter = Field(attribute='quarter')
    # other fields ...

    class Meta:
        model = Offering
        import_id_fields = ('ACCESSIONNUMBER', 'quarter')

    def before_import_row(self, row, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        Company.objects.get_or_create(accession_number=row.get('ACCESSIONNUMBER'))
```

```py
# models.py
class Company(models.Model):
    accession_number = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.accession_number


class Offering(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='accession_number')
    quarter = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    # other fields ...

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.company}
```

```
<- error messages ->
1 get() returned more than one Offering -- it returned 2!
2 get() returned more than one Offering -- it returned 2!
...
22 get() returned more than one Offering -- it returned 2!
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track but your implementation is not quite right.

You are right to use `import_id_fields`.  The fields you declare here **must uniquely identify a single instance of a row object**.

The object instance is identified using:

```py
return self.get_queryset().get(**params)
```

where each `param` has a key of your **attribute** field name, and the value is the cleaned value taken from the import file.

Therefore, this line won't work:

```py
import_id_fields = ('ACCESSIONNUMBER', 'quarter')
```

because you don't have an attribute on `Offering` called `ACCESSIONNUMBER`.  To fix this, declare your field using this syntax:

```py
industry_group_type = Field(attribute='company__accession_number', column_name='ACCESSIONNUMBER')
```

(you need to follow the [model relation](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#customize-resource-options) to refer to `accession_number`.  I assume your csv import column name is `ACCESSIONNUMBER`).

If this combination of fields does not uniquely identify a single instance, then you will see the error:

```
get() returned more than one Offering -- it returned 2!
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I followed your answer and I edited my code, but now it doesn't work at all, I get this error ` Company matching query does not exist.` . Also when I print the row in `before_import_row` method I get something like this ` OrderedDict([('ACCESSIONNUMBER', '0001612444-21-000001'), ('INDUSTRYGROUPTYPE', 'Pooled Investment Fund', ...)])` I think OrderedDict key names should be like the resource class attibute names, Right?

Comment: I realise that you will need the `before_import_row()` because you will need to create a Company if it doesn't exist.  Therefore, re-add that method. (I've updated the answer)