# Use import_export django library to import personnalized export CSV

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have two action in my application.
First I export data to CSV using specific resources (see below) to have personalized Headers and Name of specific foreign Key instead Id.
It's OK for Export CSV file.
For Import this after modification ... An error raises :
**Integrity Error: (1048, "Column 'produit_id' cannot be null") **

Below is the Resource Class for Greffons to get specific columns name and ordering columns in Meta.

```
class GreffonResource(resources.ModelResource):
    comm = fields.Field(
        column_name='Pre-Commandes',
        attribute='comm',
    )
    greffons = fields.Field(
        column_name='Greffons',
        attribute='greffons',
    )
    objectif = fields.Field(
        column_name='Objectifs',
        attribute='objectif',
    )
    realise = fields.Field(
        column_name='Realises',
        attribute='realise',
    )
    reussi = fields.Field(
        column_name='Reussis',
        attribute='reussi',
    )
    variete = fields.Field(
        column_name='Variete',
        attribute='produit__variete',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Produit, 'nom')
    )
    espece = fields.Field(
        column_name='Espece',
        attribute='produit__espece',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Produit, 'nom')
    )
    portegreffe = fields.Field(
        column_name='Porte Greffe',
        attribute='produit__portegreffe',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Produit, 'nom')
    )
    produit = fields.Field(
        column_name='Produits',
        attribute='produit',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Produit, 'id')
    )
    rang = fields.Field(
        column_name='Rangs',
        attribute='rang',
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Greffons
        fields = ('id', 'produit', 'variete', 'espece', portegreffe', 'comm', 'greffons', 'objectif', 'realise', 'reussi', 'rang')
        export_order = ['id', 'produit', 'variete', 'espece', portegreffe', 'comm', 'greffons', 'objectif', 'realise', 'reussi', 'rang']
        import_id_fields = ('id', 'produit')
```

After Export CSV file, I change data inside and import it after but error :(
Below is the code to import data after POST.

```
produit_resource = GreffonResource()
dataset = Dataset()
new_datas = request.FILES['myfile']
imported_data = dataset.load(new_datas.read().decode(), format='csv')
if categorie == "GREFFONS":
result = produit_resource.import_data(imported_data, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)
```

[EDIT] : Finally the issue is due to editor application who add some empty line after the end of file ...

I edit my Resource Class to add some other field related to Produit ... It's ok for Export but when I import them ....
I've got two new errors depending if I let 'produit' into import_id_fields or not ...

> DoesNotExist at /produits/import_xls/ Produit matching query does not
> exist.

or

> MultipleObjectsReturned at /produits/import_xls/ get() returned more
> than one Greffons -- it returned 2!

I checked and my column contain unique ID ...

Finally I just need to export file with ID and Other ForeignKey Text Value (Name) + Import again from ID of produit ... Please help again ^^

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have a `Produits.nom` value in your csv which does not map to a single existing `Produit` instance.  This is causing a create with a null value which fails.

You need to look at your import file and check all values of the 'Produits' column.  Ensure that any value in there can map to a `nom` entry in the `Produit` table.  Could it be that there are empty values for 'nom' which are being interpreted as null?

This line declares that your csv column called 'Produits' will have a value which maps to `Produit.nom`:

```py
produit = fields.Field(
    column_name='Produits',
    attribute='produit',
    widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Produit, 'nom')
)
```

If you cannot find the source of the problem, the best thing is to step through the import with a debugger and you should see exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Finally the cause of this error is due to software used to edit file added a lot of empty line after ... 
I choose textedit to modify it and it's OK ...
I edit my initial question because after that I tried somehting works for Export but issue for Import (too much answer for Get) ... if you can help me again ;)

Comment: it's best to post a new question instead of changing the original (otherwise it gets confusing).  To fix your error, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72934745/39296) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71675065/39296), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68046391/39296).

Comment: OK for next time ;)
My issue was because I used ForeignKey to get other field into my export instead just goog attribute good relation (produit__variete__nom)